# Twelfth Night: Why does Olivia call Sir Toby “cousin”?

Tags: shakespeare

I’m reading *Twelfth Night*, where in Act 1, Scene 5, Olivia says to Sir Toby Belch:

> **Olivia**:  Cousin, cousin, how have you come so early by this lethargy?

How come she’s calling her uncle “cousin”?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the original sense of the word in English, per the OED, was:

> A collateral relative more distant than a brother or sister; a kinsman or kinswoman, a relative; formerly very frequently applied to a nephew or niece.

Which also includes the following citation:

> - 1599 Shaks. *Much Ado* I. ii. 2 ― How now brother, where is my cosen your son?

Comment: It sounds a bit rustic/dated to me now, but in my youth **cuz** was common enough in UK SE greetings - *"How's it going, cuz/mate/old man/my friend?"* It didn't imply any blood relationship at all, distant or close.

Comment: The mathematician in me wants to point out that uncle-niece are zeroth cousins once removed.  (But the linguist is objecting that this is not how the word *cousin* is used.)

Answer (score 2):

A similar usage exists in modern-day slang ([source](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cuz)):

> ***cuz***  (n.) - cousin; friend; brotha; homey/homie

I have been called this by two of my uncles (thus adhering to the original sense), and it is used intermittently between family members. I am not sure how widespread the practice is outside of gang culture–which I'm not involved in–but I can attest to its usage in parts of the U.S. Midwest.